# Values not showing on JavaFX combo box

Tags: java, javafx, combobox

I have this code below, for populating values on the JavaFX `ComboBox`.

The System.out inside is printing state name inside for each loop, but the state name is not showing on the combo box.

```
@FXML private ComboBox<String> cmboState = new ComboBox<String>();

ObservableList<String> stateList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

stateList.clear();
stateService = (StateService) App.getAppContext().getBean("StateService");
List<State> states = stateService.findAllState();
cmboState.setItems(stateList);
for (State state : states) {
    System.out.println(state.getStateName());
    stateList.add(state.getStateName());
}
stateList.add(0, "Select one");
cmboState.setItems(stateList);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no actual problem with this snippet, it is working, so please make sure that `stateList` is not erased somewhere else in your code.

Also, calling `cmboState.setItems(stateList);` twice is useless, as it is an `ObservableList`:

```
cmboState.setItems(stateList); // Here stateList is empty
for (int i = 0; i<3; i++) {            
    stateList.add("aaa" + i);
}
stateList.add(0, "Select one");
```

So my best guess is that you erase this list somewhere else, therefore the list of items in your `ComboBox` will be also erased.

Comment: Just to mention: I had the same issue because I was setting my `ComboBox` to a `new ComboBox()` in my FXML file's `initialize()` method. I fixed it by removing that statement. (FXML creates all the required objects automatically.)